# Can't access xampp server through another device in lan/wifi

Tags: xampp, localhost, wifi, lan, modem

I have just set up a wi-fi network at home. I have all my files on my desktop computer (192.168.1.33) and want to access localhost over there from another computer (192.168.1.2).

On my desktop I can access localhost through the normal [http://localhost] or [http://192.168.1.33]. Apache is running on port 80 as usual.

But I can't access it on my mobile or laptop connected to same wifi network using [http://192.168.1.33].

I am using Dlink DSL 2750U modem.

Comment: **I connected laptop to modem using Ethernet and not WiFi and tried to access server using [http://192.168.1.33], I was able to access it but when i connect same laptop using WiFi of that modem and try to access server using same IP i.e [http://192.168.1.33], then I see error -> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.33 **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your visiblity status, make sure wireless devices are visible to wireline ones and it will work fine

Comment: may I know to change visibility status? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please check your firewall setting on your desktop. Perhaps the firewall blocks the incoming request to the port 80.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I have checked everything before posting my query.

Comment: can you ping your desktop while using your modem's wifi?